# ncmpc - spaces in search query

Tags: search, music-player

How can I use spaces in my search query in ncmpc (window 5), when looking for a particular type of tag?

For example,

```
artist:radiohead
```

works. But,

```
artist:owl city
```

doesn't. I've tried thing like:

```
artist:'owl city'
artist:"owl city"
artist:owl\ city
artist:{owl city}
```

but none of that works.

Thank you

Comment: Reason enough to install [ncmpcpp](http://unkart.ovh.org/ncmpcpp/)...

Comment: @jasonwryan: I tried it, but it seemed to use a lot more resources than ncmpc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `artist:owl%city` does the trick.